# how do i use initialize variables if i miss '{' syntax

Tags: visual-c++

I am making my own fun project about multiplying numbers until it gives 1.

I started without using class and it worked fine, but the code looked very messy and unorganized.

this is my c++ code:

```
 '  #include "multiply.h"
   #include<iostream>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <string>

   #define log(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

     unsigned int multiply::dividenumbers(unsigned int& numbers)
: nums(numbers)
     {
log("you found 0! Now divide with numbers from 1 to 9! Chose 0 to exit 
        division!")
    LOOP:
std::cin >> dividend;
if (dividend > 9 && dividend < 2) {
    log("you cannot chose this number!")
        goto LOOP;
}
res = nums / dividend;
if (dividend == 0) {
    return res;
}

if (res) {
    log("whoops! you lost the game :(")
        exit(1);
}
return res;
      }

    unsigned int multiply::removezeroes(unsigned int* numbers)
:num(std::to_string(*numbers)), nums(*numbers)
    {
num = std::to_string(nums);
for (auto i : num) {
    if (i == '0') { continue; }
    digits += i;
}
nums = stoi(digits);
log(nums)
    for (auto i : num) {
        if (i == '0') { dividenumbers(nums); }
    }
return nums;
     }'
```

and my header file:

```
     'class multiply
      {
      public:
unsigned int dividenumbers(unsigned int& numbers);
unsigned int removezeroes(unsigned int* numbers);
    private:
unsigned int dividend, nums, res;
std::string num, digits;
    };'
```

the code above should compile, but the error gives my this: "expected this {c"

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int multiply::dividenumbers(unsigned int& numbers)
: nums(numbers) { ... }
```

This is not a valid syntax. It somewhat resembles a constructor initializer list - but as the name suggests, those are only valid for constructors. `dividenumbers` is not a constructor.

If you wish to assing `numbers` parameter to member variable `nums`, just say so:

```
unsigned int multiply::dividenumbers(unsigned int& numbers) {
  nums = numbers;
  ...
}
```

Comment: tnx i get it now.